# How do I do IN syntax with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I need to do this using linq chaining syntax. I have:

```
string[] arr = new string[] {"Chicago", "NewYork"};

var a = Members.Where(x => x.City == <here I want to get all members in chicago or newyork)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a simple `Contains`.

```
var a = Members.Where(x => arr.Contains(x.City));
```

Comment: If I had to use the JOIN syntax or the IN syntax, how would I do it (although your answer works like a charm)

Comment: @Dotnet, what do you mean?  "JOIN or IN" - They are very different things.

Comment: Do you mean 'IN' as the 'JOIN' criterion?

Comment: If it wasn't for the Contains, I could have used a JOIN (Members with arr) or used a IN (Members in arr) to get the same result.

Comment: @Dotnet, oh.  The Join would perform much worse than the Contains I'd have to assume.

Comment: @Dotnet, check out this blog entry: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2008/05/09/using-linq-to-perform-quot-where-in-value1-value2-quot-queries.aspx

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old, but I thought this would help new readers of this post.

Similar to [code4life](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598793/how-do-i-do-in-syntax-with-linq/4599100#4599100), I use an extension method.  The difference, though, is that I use generics so this will work with multiple types.

You can read my [blog post](http://www.thecodepage.com/post.aspx?id=28197601-0cae-48a2-aadf-992e073f8690) to see more information about how to do this, but the main idea is this:

By adding this extension method to your code:

```
public static bool IsIn<T>(this T source, params T[] values)
{
    return values.Contains(source);
}
```

you can perform your search like this:

```
var a = Members.Where(x => x.City.IsIn("Chicago", "NewYork");
```

It works on any type (as long as you create a good equals method).  Any value type for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Static extensions work well with your LINQ needs:

```
// add this class to your project...
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool IsIn(this string target, params string[] testValues)
    {
        return testValues.Contains(target);
    }
}
```

And now your original code can be changed like this:

```
// quick and dirty code:
var a = Members.Where(x => x.City.IsIn("Chicago", "NewYork");

// less quick and dirty code:
string[] arr = new string[] {"Chicago", "NewYork"};    
var a = Members.Where(x => x.City.IsIn(arr);
```